# Is there any documentation regarding getting message from ActiveMQ via STOMP protocol using C#

Tags: c#, activemq-classic, stomp

I am trying to receive/send message from queue of activeMQ using stomp protocol using c#. As I don't know much about activemq and stomp. So I'm searching for some proper document or sample code by which I can learn step by step.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Apache.NMS.Stomp.ConnectionFactory factory  = new Apache.NMS.Stomp.ConnectionFactory(new Uri("stomp:tcp://localhost:61613"));
        IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        ISession session = connection.CreateSession();
        IDestination destination = session.GetDestination("/queue/notification");
        IMessageConsumer consumer = session.CreateConsumer(destination);
        connection.Start();
        consumer.Listener += new MessageListener(OnMessage);
        Console.WriteLine("Consumer started, waiting for messages... (Press ENTER to stop.)");
        Console.ReadLine();
        connection.Close();
    }
    private static void OnMessage(IMessage message)
    { 
        try
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("Median-Server (.NET): Message received"); 
            ITextMessage msg = (ITextMessage)message; 
            message.Acknowledge();
            Console.WriteLine(msg.Text);
        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("---");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
            Console.WriteLine("---"); 
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

}
I have tried this. Is it a correct way to make stomp connection.

Comment: The sample code seems fine, you should really try and ask a question that's more targeted.  Does your code not work?

Comment: Yes it's working when i am adding tcp in uri. When I am passing "stomp://localhost:61613" only then error pop's out.Even though I have changed activemq.xml file.

Comment: error is "Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed"

Comment: That's because stomp:// is not a valid transport protocol.  Use tcp:// for TCP connections and ssl:// for SSL connections.

Comment: But I want to use stomp protocol then still i have to use tcp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are client libraries for STOMP in various languages, for .NET there's the [Apache.NMS.Stomp](http://activemq.apache.org/nms/) library which puts a JMS type facade around STOMP semantics.  If you want to get more technical and learn what the STOMP protocol really is, then the [STOMP](http://stomp.github.com/stomp-specification-1.2.html) spec is quite clear and easy to understand.  And of course ActiveMQ's own site has some documentation on its [STOMP suppor](http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html)t that you should read.  Some web searching will also quickly net you some nice [blog posts](http://www.gavincoates.com/c-activemq-stomp) on using the NMS.Stomp library to interact with ActiveMQ.